# Is this first order version of the Collatz conjecture decidable in peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, model-theory, peano-axioms, collatz-conjecture

Let $\phi(x)$ be a first order formula in the language of arithmetic with one free variable $x$. Consider the sentence $\psi_\phi$, defined as:

$$\phi(0)\wedge \phi(1) \wedge   (\forall x \phi(x) \to \phi(2x)) \wedge (\forall  x \quad 2\not |x \to (\phi(3x+1) \to \phi(x))) \to \forall x \phi(x)$$

A positive answer to the Collatz conjecture would imply that the above sentence is valid for all $\phi$.

However, I'm wondering whether this statement can be violated in nonstandard models of arithmetic.

If such a nonstandard model of arithmetic, I would like to see a proof that there is a $\phi$ with $\text{Con}(\text{PA}\cup\psi_\phi)$.

If you think that this first order version of the Collatz conjecture should still hold, I can't expect you to give me a prove for that, since this would probably be as hard as proving the Collatz conjecture. However, I would like to hear some reasons why, when one believes in the Collatz conjecture in $\Bbb N$, one should be able to prove the validity of all the $\psi_\phi$ only with methods from PA.

Comment: You do realize the actual Collatz conjecture is already expressible as a single first-order statement in the language of arithmetic, right?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: How exactly?

Comment: If we let $f(m,n)$ denote the result of applying the Collatz iteration $m$ times starting at $n$, then $f$ is computable and hence expressible by a first-order arithmetic formula. The conjecture is then just $\forall n \exists m f(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Note that if the Collatz conjecture is true then PA can definitely prove the termination of the sequence starting from $n$ for each **standard** $n$. But that still would not imply that PA proves the Collatz conjecture, since if PA is consistent then PA is ω-incomplete. Also there are 2 ways the Collatz conjecture can be false. If there is a non-trivial cycle, then PA can prove its existence and hence disprove the Collatz conjecture. But if there is a non-cyclic sequence then PA may not be able to prove its existence since it is a Π1-sentence.

Answer (score 4):

The standard formulation of the Collatz conjecture is already first-order expressible. This is because we can code *finite sequences* of natural numbers as natural numbers, in a way simple enough that first-order arithmetic can "see." To write the Collatz conjecture in first-order logic, what we do is first define a "Collatz sequence" as a finite sequence $s$ of natural numbers such that for all $n$ with $n+1\in dom(s)$, if $s(n)$ is even then $2s(n+1)=s(n)$ and if $s(n)$ is odd then $s(n+1)=3s(n)+1$. Then the Collatz conjecture says that for any number $n$, there is a Collatz sequence $s$ and a number $k$ such that $s(0)=n$ and $s(k)=1$.

Technical note: representing sequences is actually slightly tricky if we don't have a primitive symbol for exponentiation; see e.g. the first few pages of http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math502-03/meta9.pdf.

Once you see this, it should be clear that in fact your scheme is a consequence of the standard first-order version of the Collatz conjecture, and if the Collatz conjecture is false, then we can build a $\varphi$ such that $\psi_\varphi$ is false in the standard model. So your question is almost certainly as hard as the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: I would like to ask for your opinion on whether you believe PA decides Collatz or not, and what evidence you happen to know of that informs your belief. I feel that it's likely that PA decides Collatz, because it seems simple enough to likely fall under "decidable small cases", analogous to how PA can prove the outputs of the busy beaver function on small inputs. However, I have completely zero evidence, whether mathematical or empirical, for my guess. So I would like to hear your opinion. =)

Comment: If you don't know anything about Collatz, then never mind and thanks anyway!